# How to find out which SIM is receiving an incoming call in android?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager

I am listening to a broadcast receiver. In a dual SIM, how do I know which SIM is receiving an incoming call. The intent bundle only contains the state and the incoming phone number.

```
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);    
}
```

Comment: No, I didn't find a solution